# Ocaml how to call a method in one class from another class

Tags: class, object, ocaml

I'm having some truble with objects and classes. I'm trying to call a method from the class kid in the class family to add a kid in the family anytime I want but I get an error I don't quiet understand.

```
class virtual person name lastName sex =
    object
        val name = (name:string)
        val mutable lastName = (lastName:string)
        val sex = (sex:char)
    end;;

class man name lastName=
    object
        inherit person name lastName 'm'
        method printNameAndLastName = (name ^ " " ^ lastName)
        method changeLastName newLastName = lastName <- newLastName
        method printLastName = lastName
end;;

class woman name lastName =
    object
        inherit person name lastName 'w'
        method printNameAndLastName = (name ^ " " ^ lastName)
        method changeLastName newLastName = lastName <- newLastName
        method printLastName = lastName
end;;

class child name sex=
    object
        inherit person name "" 'm'
        method printNameAndLastName = (name ^ " " ^ lastName)
        method changeLastName newLastName = lastName <- newLastName
        method printLastName = lastName
end;;

class family familyName man woman=
    object
        val man = man
        val woman = woman
        val mutable kids = ([] :string list)
        initializer woman#changeLastName (man#printLastName)
        method addKid kid = kids <- (kid#printLastName)::kids
        method printFamily = (man#printNameAndLastNAme ^ ", " ^ woman#printNameAndLastName)
end;;



Error: Some type variables are unbound in this type:
         class family :
           'a ->
           (< printLastName : 'c; printNameAndLastNAme : string; .. > as 'b) ->
           (< changeLastName : 'c -> unit; printNameAndLastName : string;
              .. >
            as 'd) ->
           object
             val mutable kids : string list
             val man : 'b
             val woman : 'd
             method addKid : < printLastName : string; .. > -> unit
             method printFamily : string
           end
       The method addKid has type
         (< printLastName : string; .. > as 'e) -> unit
       where 'e is unbound
```

The error happens when I add the method addKid. also the last method printFamily, I'd like to add to it the list of kids names after the name of the man and woman, making it look like this:

- (string * string) * string list = (("man", "woman"), ["kid1" ;
  "kid2"]).

I have been experimenting this but i couldn't merge the strings with the list, getting the error expected (string*string)*string.

Thank you for you time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types of all values in the class should be bound to its definition. For example:

```
# class ident x = object
    method x = x
  end;;
    Characters 6-11:
  class ident x = object
        ^^^^^
Error: Some type variables are unbound in this type:
         class ident : 'a -> object method x : 'a end
       The method x has type 'a where 'a is unbound
```

That means, that you need either to bound it to a concrete type:

```
class ident x = object
    method x : int = x
  end;;
class ident : int -> object method x : int end
```

Or make your class polymorphic and bound value to a newly introduced type variable:

```
# class ['a] ident x = object
    method x : 'a = x
  end;;
class ['a] ident : 'a -> object method x : 'a end
```

In your case,  `man`, `woman` and `kid` are unbound. Since, every time you define a class the equally named type is created, you can bound them to `man`, `woman` and `child` (and also fix a typo in the method)

```
class family familyName man woman =
    object
        val man : man  = man
        val woman : woman = woman
        val mutable kids = ([] :string list)
        initializer woman#changeLastName (man#printLastName)
        method addKid (kid : child) = kids <- (kid#printLastName)::kids
        method printFamily = (man#printNameAndLastName ^ ", " ^ woman#printNameAndLastName)
end;;
```

Comment: that works, thanks. What about the last part when I print the family, how can I print 2 concatinated strings + the list of kids after that without having to do it twice?

Comment: first of all you're not printing, but converting to string. That's different. In order to convert a string list to string you can use `String.concat` that also accepts a separator. Also, using `sprintf` (or any other printf-family` function is very useful.

Comment: I did it with String.concat but it makes strings from the list. Is there maybe a way that the concatinated string is made of the two strings and the list like I wrote in the example above in my question.
Thanks ahead for your help, it was very useful.

Comment: well you can just prepend parents to the list, e.g., `String.concat ", "(man#printNameAndLastName :: woman#printNameAndLastName :: kids)`